# Object of classes and attributes

Tags: javascript, class, object, web

Hey guy I am studying and I am trying to solve this hard exercise.

[image]

on the above picture I am trying to implement this into a code: however I find it extremely hard. I have tried the following at the moment, don't know if its correct or not, can someone please help me?

just some info that the assignment says:
-The attribute product should be an objekt of the class Product

- Shipping adress and billing address should be an object of the class Adress
- User should also be an object of the class User
- CalculateOrder (should calculate order and sum the price for everything
- Calculate vat should add 25 %
- printAllorders() should print all orders

what is mean by "object of the class"

Answer (score 0):

> what is mean by "object of the class"

Object off the class means you build an instance of it like

```
Proudct p = new Product();
```

With this you build an **instance** or **object** of the Class **Product**

Your class lineItem has an Attribute Product.
This means that the attribute is not of an primitive type like int, boolean  .... it is of type product

```
public class LineItem(){
    int id;
    double price;
    int quantity;
    Product prod;
 }
```